# jQuery parentsUntil not firing in else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

oK, This is strange...I have the same code that will work great in the if statment...but wont fire once it gets to the `parentsUntil` when it hits the else statement  ????

```
 if(sArray.length > 400){

 $.each(sArray,  function(key, item){

                    $("!#"+item).parentsUntil(".#jstree").filter(".#jstree-closed").each(function () { 
                            $aTree.jstree("close_all", this); 
                            }); 
                  });

else{

 $.each(sArray,  function(key, item){

                    $("!#"+item).parentsUntil(".#jstree").filter(".#jstree-closed").each(function () { 
//IT IS NOT MAKING IT HERE
                            $aTree.jstree("close_all", this); 
                            }); 
                  });


}
```

Comment: Console show any errors?

Comment: no errors being shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed 2 } and what the console give to you with that :

```
if(sArray.length > 400){

     $.each(sArray,  function(key, item){
        $("#"+item).parentsUntil(".jstree").filter(".jstree-closed").each(function () { 
            $aTree.jstree("check_node", this); 
        }); 
    });

}// Was missing
else{

$.each(sArray,  function(key, item){
    console.log($("#"+item).parentsUntil(".jstree").filter(".jstree-closed"));
    $("#"+item).parentsUntil(".jstree").filter(".jstree-closed").each(function () { 
            //IT IS NOT MAKING IT HERE
            console.log("pass");
            $aTree.jstree("check_node", this); 
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: but if that was the case....my first if would not fire......and thats not the case

Comment: What do you mean by wrong ? No output into the console ? Error ?